# How can I add upload Image feature to Facebook Comments Plugin?

Tags: facebook, plugins, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-comments

I successfully implemented facebook comments plugin in my website.But it only allows users to post only text data.

I searched a lot but unable to find resources for these question:

1. How to add upload Image feature to this plugin?
2. Is there a way to make the uses post he comment just by pressing enter rather than clicking Post button(Remove Post button and make enter keyboard key as default submit button)

Incase the ans is No for any above questions:

Please suggest  any plugin's that helps me to achieve those features. The users should be able to post comments and upload images with out signup to that plugin providers

Answer (score 0):

> How to add upload Image feature to this plugin?

Not possible.

Facebook has not implemented image upload for the Comments plugin, and you can not “add” anything to it yourself.

> Is there a way to make the uses post he comment just by pressing enter rather than clicking Post button(Remove Post button and make enter keyboard key as default submit button)

No.

There is not configuration option for this, and since the plugin runs inside an iframe from a different domain, you don’t have any access to it via JavaScript either.

Comment: Ohkk ... Nice and Thanks :). But are there any plugin's that helps me to achieve those features. The users should be able to post comments and upload images with out signup to that plugin providers

Answer (score 0):

As of Sept 2010 FB has an "add image" icon on the FB plugin, but it does not work all the time. Last night it worked fine on 20 or so pages, and today on 5 more. Then just now, on a recently modified page, it no longer works. Text only.

Comment: Can you please be more specific. Add some tags for the question, write the snippets that you are using, and refer to any documentation that you have followed